# How to specify a tab delimiter in PapaParse?

Tags: papaparse

I receive a delimiter like so:

```
var delimiter = process.argv[3];
if (!delimiter) {
  console.log('Please specify a delimiter as the second argument in the CLI');
  process.exit(0);
}
console.log('with delimiter:', delimiter);
```

And I attempt to use it with PapaParse like this:

```
  Papa.parse(fs.createReadStream(__dirname + relativePathToFile, 'utf8'), {
    delimiter: delimiter,
    header: true,
    skipEmptyLines: true,
```

But regardless of passing in `\t` or `\\t` from CLI, neither works. What value exactly does PapaParse want us to pass for it to be identified as the tab delimiter?

Answer (score 2):

I've had success passing in \t directly, like so:
    delimiter: '\t'
But I'm not sure how that translates to pulling it from a function.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but it should work

```
Papa.parse(fs.createReadStream(__dirname + relativePathToFile, 'utf8'), {
    delimiter: delimiter === "\\t" ? "\t" : delimiter,
    header: true,
    skipEmptyLines: true,
```

Answer (score -2):

Specify spaces as required, for tab delimiter should have 5 spaces